# Dynamic comparison of Profile id and userid fails in trigger

Tags: trigger, profile, user, dynamic-soql, dynamic-apex

**How do i correctly assign the userid and profileid to make a dynamic comparison. ?**

// if i hardcode the owner's profileid and userid the IF gets evaluated to true, however if i dynamically compare it does not not evaluate to true.

```
    Profile p  = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Sales'];
    Id salesprofileid = p.Id;
    system.debug('Is the profile id correct: ' + salesprofileid); 

    User u = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name = 'Guest User'];
    Id GuestUserid = u.Id;


    for (Account acc : accounts) {

        if (oldMap.get(acc.Id).OwnerId != acc.OwnerId && oldMap.get(acc.Id).OwnerId ==GuestUserid && acc.OwnerId.ProfileId==salesprofileid) 
         {
            system.debug('does it get here');     // No 
         }
    }
```

Comment: why would a guest user ever have a Profile of `Sales`?

Comment: Guest User does not have a profile of Sales. The profile for guest user is Guest and license is 'Guest User license'. What I am checking for is this - PreviousOwner  = Guest and CurrentOwner.Profile = 'Sales'

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working for you is this condition:

```
acc.OwnerId.ProfileId==salesprofileid
```

As this logic is in (or called by) an Account Trigger, only the values on the triggered object (i.e. Account) are implicitly available in any of the Trigger context variables (like `Trigger.New`)

You will need to query for the parent values for all Accounts in the Trigger.new variable and stuff them in a map before executing your comparison

```
// Pass 1 - Get parent values
Map<Id,Account> acctsById = new Map<Id,Account> ([
   SELECT Id, Owner.ProfileId FROM Account
   WHERE Id = :newMap.keySet()]);

// Pass 2 - Examine Accounts for those of interest
for (Account acc : accounts) {

    if (oldMap.get(acc.Id).OwnerId != acc.OwnerId &&
        oldMap.get(acc.Id).OwnerId ==GuestUserid && 
        acctsById.get(acc.Id).Owner.ProfileId==salesprofileid) 
     {
        do something useful 
     }
}
```